# When using DrawerLayout the activity displays a green screen with "android...DrawerLayout" and no content

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have looked to see if anyone else had this issue and I had no luck. I am assuming it is an issue with the dependencies, but I am not too sure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"/>


</FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This displays: [What the design page and text page shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvLph.png)

Here is my build.gradle file (Module: app):

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0-alpha1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you, and I hope I didn't miss anything really obvious.
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different versions of `appcompat` & `drawerlayout`: `rc02`-`alpha1`.

These two:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Should be the same version. However, `v28` has the Android Studio Preview issue and you can change it to use stable versions like `27.1.1`.

Also, you can try this too which somehow solves the issue by using `27.1.1` without need to change anything, just add it inside `Build.gradle`:

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == "com.android.support") {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyways, I'm not sure why you used `com.android.support:drawerlayout` but I'd suggest using this instead:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02' // or 27.1.1
```

As already [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer#AddDependency) suggested.